# Trying to understand C code(semaphores & syncing them)

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm trying to understand some C code regarding operating system /Creating threads syncing

```
line 1: targs[0]->id=1; /* thread number 1 */
line 2: targs[0]->sec=1; /* how long to sleep */
line 3: targs[0]->signal[1]=1; /* which threads to wake up when done */
line 4: targs[0]->signal[4]=1;
line 5: sem_init(&sem[targs[0]->id-1],SHARED,1); /* start waiting or running? */
line 6: pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, tfunc, (void *) targs[0]);
```

My question is. What does "sem_init()" do?, on line 5: by the ((&sem[targs[0]->id-1],SHARED,1);), "&sem" referrs to the array i made which is not here, the targs[0] gets an Id minus 1? is this correct?

pthread_create= creates a thread, which has to be zero for it to run?

Comment: `sem` array starts at index 0. You assign a `1` to `targs[0]->id` and `-1` adjusts the range to start from 0 again.

Comment: Questions whether something is correct are hardly answerable if most of the relevant code is missing.

Comment: I'm not allowed by stackoverflow to show too much code :(

Comment: suggest: post a [mcve], not the whole world.

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create= creates a thread, which has to be zero for it to run?`  What do you mean by: `which has to be zero for it to run`?

Comment: I am confident that you can post more code as long as you also provide some text explaining it. Code-only-posts should be avoided.